# An error has occured during report processing : Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, reportbuilder

I am trying to run my report built with report builder, and i found this error.

When i try to check my database server, it's running up
But the issue continue to persist.
I try to verify the datasource credential, and everything seems working good